# MySQL convert table to latin1 does not convert foreign characters to correct representation

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

I have a database that serves a PHP application with non English characters stored in it, for example: `ç ã é`.

Previously, this database had stored and displayed these characters correctly, but after backing it up and restoring, some characters in their places have been replaced with combinations like `Ã§Ã£` when it should show up c

Clearly this was a backup or restore charset oversight, however I'm unable to retrieve a previous good version of the database.

This dump file is all that remains of the database and it also shows combinations like `Ã§Ã£` in the place of `çã` when opened in a text editor.

I've tried converting one of the tables from utf8_unicode_ci to latin1_swedish_ci and the reverse, however no effect.

```
ALTER TABLE test CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE test CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

How do I solve this problem.

Thank you.

**NOTE:** `utf8_decode` from PHP is able to convert `Ã§Ã£` to `ça`, but I would like to solve this problem at the source.

---

**Update:** I was able to query the affected tables and have it return the proper characters with the following query.

`SELECT convert(cast(convert(field_name using  latin1) as binary) using utf8) FROM affectedTable`

---

**Update 2:**

The query bellow was able to convert the characters into their proper UTF-8 representation.

```
SELECT convert(cast(convert(field_name using  latin1) as binary) using utf8) FROM affectedTable
```

Therefore following the approach in the previous query, if you run the follow three queries for each table affected it should convert the characters into UTF-8.

```
ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1;
ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET binary;
ALTER TABLE table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Thats it, characters like `Ã§Ã£` will be converted to `ça` and so on.

This worked with MySQL 5.6.20 - Community Server on Windows, it did not with MySQL 5.5.42 - Community Server on Linux. Maybe someone knows a cross version/OS solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the data in your table is stored as latin1, but is actually utf8.

When doing 'CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET', it usually attempts to basically convert the characters from 'latin1' to 'utf8'

To change the type without changing the data, you need to first convert the column to a binary column and then to the final destination character set which should avoid any actual character conversion.

This is discussed in the documentation here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-conversion.html

Comment: No.  `CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET` is used only for changing _both_ the charset and contents of a column from, say, latin1 to utf8.  `Ã§Ã£` implies something else.

Answer (score 0):

`Ã§Ã£` is the Mojibake for `çã`.

Perform

SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...
If you get hex `C3A7C3A3` for `çã`, that is the utf8 encoding.  However, if you see `Ã§Ã£` for the `col`, latin1 is creeping in.  If the column is declared `CHARACTER SET utf8`, then the table is fine; the connection is broken.  You need `SET NAMES utf8` or the equivalent when connecting.

If you get hex `C383C2A7C383C2A3`, you have "double encoding", and the is a different solution.  After all the `ALTERs` you have done, I would not be surprised if you have this mess.

The "2-step ALTER" applies when you wrote utf8 bytes with SET NAMES latin1 to a CHARACTER SET latin1 column. The symptom is often (but not always) that your `çã` is showing as `Ã§Ã£`.

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

(Your 3-step alter was overkill.)

When INSERTing a string, 3 things make a difference on whether the inserted value is good or bad.

```
⚈  Data in client is _encoded_ latin1 versus utf8
⚈  SET NAMES (or equivalent) is latin1 versus utf8
⚈  The target column's CHARACTER SET is ascii vs latin1 vs utf8
```